# How to download multiple files from various links using wget

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting

Suppose I have various images that I want to download and I have the links available:

https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1548363585-5b1241ee3b85?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80

https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1556648011-e01aca870a81?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80

I don't want to type it in one by one

```
wget https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1548363585-5b1241ee3b85?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80

wget https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1556648011-e01aca870a81?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80
```

How can I achieve this? I have read that saving these links in a .txt file and using a for loop is not a correct way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have the URLs in a file like this:

```
https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1548363585-5b1241ee3b85?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80
https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1556648011-e01aca870a81?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80
```

Then you could run

```
wget --input-file=file
```

to download the images as described by @[Kusalananda](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/579400/how-to-download-multiple-files-from-various-links-using-wget#comment1078495_579404).

Comment: Or just use `wget --input-file=somefile`.

Comment: There's a good chance people may want to use `-x` with this as well, to force it to download to the corresponding local directory that matches each URL pattern.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep everything in the same script, `--input-file` / `-i` option can also read from `stdin`

```
wget -i - << EOF
https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1548363585-5b1241ee3b85?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80
https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1556648011-e01aca870a81?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80
EOF
```

Comment: Or `<< 'EOF'` to avoid problems with `$` characters (unlikely in URIs, though more likely than backtick, backslash which would also be a problem here but are illegal in URIs)